# Does using Disqus decreases reader interaction rate?

Tags: disqus

While researching on importing comments into Disqus, I read several articles about that "adapting Disqus" caused interaction rate to drop

- http://blog.hostilefork.com/importing-comments-with-disqus-api/
- http://www.wpbeginner.com/opinion/switching-away-from-disqus-review-increased-comments-by-304/

Do someone happened to have switched, and saw how interaction rate changes?

Comment: I switched to Disqus and saw improvements on one of my sites yet saw big drop in interaction on another.

Comment: @DwillX Just wondering do you happen to allow anonymous commenting on both sites?

Comment: No actually I didn't allow it.  In hindsight maybe I should of.